# How to convert excel if else condition in python dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert excel if else condition in python dataframe columns, can anyone help me out in this:

**Input: df**

```
   Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  MaxValue
0  John1  John2  John3  John4      10       3       5       7        10
1  Sony1  Sony2  Sony3  Sony4       2      12       4       8        12
2  Mark1  Mark2  Mark3  Mark4       5      13       0       3        13
3  Biky1  Biky2  Biky3  Biky4       7       7       5      44        44
4  Rose1  Rose2  Rose3  Rose4       7       0       9       7         9
```

Name values may not be ended with 1/2/3 etc this may have different name also.

**Output: How to calculate the **Final_Name** column**

```
   Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  MaxValue Final_Name
0  John1  John2  John3  John4      10       3       5       7        10      John1
1  Sony1  Sony2  Sony3  Sony4       2      12       4       8        12      Sony2
2  Mark1  Mark2  Mark3  Mark4       5      13       0       3        13      Mark2
3  Biky1  Biky2  Biky3  Biky4       7       7       5      44        44      Biky4
4  Rose1  Rose2  Rose3  Rose4       7       0       9       7         9      Rose3
```

In excel we, can write something like this:

```
=IF(I2=H2,D2,IF(I2=G2,C2,IF(I2=F2,B2,IF(I2=E2,A2,""))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `filter` the df into two parts , then we use the value position locate the Name

```
v = df.filter(regex = '^Value')
name = df.filter(regex = '^Name')
df['out'] = name.values[df.index, v.columns.get_indexer(v.idxmax(1))]
df
Out[188]: 
   Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  MaxValue    out
0  John1  John2  John3  John4      10       3       5       7        10  John1
1  Sony1  Sony2  Sony3  Sony4       2      12       4       8        12  Sony2
2  Mark1  Mark2  Mark3  Mark4       5      13       0       3        13  Mark2
3  Biky1  Biky2  Biky3  Biky4       7       7       5      44        44  Biky4
4  Rose1  Rose2  Rose3  Rose4       7       0       9       7         9  Rose3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a column that will show you which 'Name' column should you return back using `idxmax()`.  Then you can `stack()` your 'Name' columns and merge this result with your created column above based on index and 'Name':

```
# Create a helper column
v_c = [c for c in df if c.startswith('Value')]
df['id_col'] = df[v_c].idxmax(axis=1).str.replace('Value','Name')

# Merge the helper column with your stacked 'Name' columns
n_c = df.filter(like='Name').columns
res = pd.merge(df[n_c].stack().reset_index(),df[['id_col']].reset_index(),left_on=['level_0','level_1'], right_on=['index','id_col'])[0]

# Assign as a column
df['Final_Name'] = res
```

prints:

```
   Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4  ...  Value4  MaxValue  id_col  Final_Name
0  John1  John2  John3  John4  ...       7        10   Name1       John1
1  Sony1  Sony2  Sony3  Sony4  ...       8        12   Name2       Sony2
2  Mark1  Mark2  Mark3  Mark4  ...       3        13   Name2       Mark2
3  Biky1  Biky2  Biky3  Biky4  ...      44        44   Name4       Biky4
4  Rose1  Rose2  Rose3  Rose4  ...       7         9   Name3       Rose3

[5 rows x 11 columns]
```